# Remove duplicated div on Cart Update in Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a new website using the help of Wordpress and Woocommerce. I created a child theme of store front and have been working on it. I needed to make a few changes on the cart page, so i overwrote the template of cart.php on my child them.

The problem i'm facing, is that when i click update cart, it duplicates the form that contains the the list of the products.

What i've tried so far, was to use the jQuery `remove();` , but since the page doesn't refresh, i can't use a document ready function or something like that for it to remove the extra divs.

Does anyone have a quick solution to it?

What i have so far is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".cart-page-desktop:not(:first)").remove();
   $(".cart-page-mobile:not(:first)").remove();
});
```

The divs that are being duplicated are called `.cart-page-desktop` and .`cart-page-mobile`.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: *when i **click update cart***  Sounds like you already have a different event and element you could target the logic on.

Comment: @Taplar i understand what you mean, but since it makes an Ajax call to refresh the cart and doesn't refresh the page, the code i'm using doesn't remove anything, because the update process takes a while. It duplicates the divs after like 5 or 6 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

After a deep search of Woocommerce custom events, i've found the `updated_cart_totals` and with the next piece of code, i solved my problem.

```
$( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
    $(".cart-page-desktop:not(:first)").remove();
    $(".cart-page-mobile:not(:first)").remove();
});
```

Posting in case it will be helpful to anyone else.